# ExtJs 5.1: Change Super Class at runtime

Tags: javascript, inheritance, extjs, extend, extjs-grid

I have the following two classes which extend the ExtJs Grid panel:

1. ReadonlyDataGrid - as name suggests, basic non-editable ExtJs grid
2. EditableDataGrid - ExtJs grid with cell & row editing plugin

Now I want to provide a new class which will extend one of the above 2 classes based on a property set by the developer in the grid JSON configuration

For Eg:

Java:

```
parentObj.put("gridType", "readonly");
```

JS:

```
Ext.define('Grid.view.GridFactory', {
extend: 'Grid.view.AbstractGridFactory',
alias: 'widget.gridfactory',
singleton: true,
create : function(model){
    var grid;
    switch(model.input.gridType)
    {
        case 'readonly':
            grid = new Grid class extending the ReadonlyDataGrid class;
            break;
        case 'editable':
            grid = new Grid class extending the EditableDataGrid class;
            break;          
    }

    return grid;
  }
});
```

Right now I have to create two separate class files to handle this.

Class 1:

```
Ext.define('Grid.view.EditableGrid',{
extend : 'Grid.view.EditableDataGrid',
.... //additional features
});
```

Class 2:

```
Ext.define('Grid.view.ReadonlyGrid',{
extend : 'Grid.view.ReadOnlyDataGrid',
.... //additional features
});
```

1. How can I merge these 2 classes into 1?
2. How can I change the extend property or extend the correct class based on the user configuration as shown above?
3. Design wise what is better? Having 1 class and changing the superClass at runtime or maintaining 2 classes but with redundant/same code?

Answer (score 1):

1. By using [mixins](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-mixins).
2. Technically you can define classes at runtime and choose any `extend` property you see fit:

```js
Ext.define('Grid.view.RuntimeGrid',{
    extend: 'Grid.view.' + (model.input.gridType === 'readonly' ? 'ReadonlyDataGrid' : 'EditableDataGrid'),
    //additional features
});
```

But that is bad practice.

3. Changing the superClass at runtime is even worse. Designwise, there are two seemly options:

   - Have two classes, but Don't Repeat Yourself: put your "redundant/same" code into a mixin and include it in both classes; OR
   - Have just one class which can be editable when configured to be so. It would accept a configuration option say `editable` and will only instantiate the relevant editing plugins / editors when the option is `true`.

Comment: Thanks for providing the options. Used mixins to put the common code in a separate class and included it as mixin in both the grid classes. But am still looking for a way to solve the inheritance problem, if possible!

Comment: Why hasn't the inheritance problem gone after using mixins?

Comment: Okay can you help me by sharing a code snippet on how to dynamically handle the inheritance using mixins?

Comment: I'm not saying you should dynamically handle inheritance. Better keep it static, follow one of the two options under 3 in my answer.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned I am following the first option under 3 in your answer. That way I have put all the common functions in a separate file and mentioned them in the `mixins` of BOTH classes. So I still have 2 classes extending different grids internally. That's the concern am talking about. Your answers was very helpful in modularizing the code!

Comment: So why having 2 classes is still a concern if they don't have redundant/same code anymore? Just choose which one to instantiate depending on the property from JSON config coming from the server side.